# Haskell: Understanding side-effects in functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning about IO in Haskell and about side-effects in functions. I know that external effects are effects that are observable outside the function, whereas internal effects are not visible from the outside. My understanding is that external effects make changes to the "real world" that lies beyond the scope of the function.

Global variable accesses are external effects, since they are visible outside of the function. However, would modifying local variables be considered as an internal effect? I believe that since these local variables are only accessible within the function itself, making changes to them would not affect the "real world", and thus this wouldn't be considered as an internal effect.

However, I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Haskell doesn't allow you to modify variables at all - that's part of what being a pure language means.

Comment: There are some libraries that allow "local mutable state" which is not visible from outside (`ST`), but that's a rather peculiar thing, which is not commonly used. It's easier to try understanding `IO` first, which always exposes side effects to the outside, even if they could be "local" and not really observable.

Comment: So in the context of purity, I am right in saying that changing the value of a variable, regardless of whether it's local or global would be considered an effect?

Comment: Modifying variables is not possible in Haskell. You can read and modify some state e.g. using `IORef`s, which will be considered an `IO` effect. Similarly, reading or modifying a `STRef` will be an `ST` effect. However, `IO` effects "propagate" through the whole program: you can't use `IO` in a function `Int -> String`, for example (you need `Int -> IO String`, exposing the IO). Instead, `ST` effects can be made "local", so that they can be used even in functions of type `Int -> String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run this program:

```
x = 5
x = 7
```

it will show:

```
    Multiple declarations of ‘x’
    Declared at: main.hs:1:1
                 main.hs:2:1
  |
2 | x = 7
```

it means, `variables` in haskell has different meaning and concept and obviously behavior than other languages. You bind values, the value in the right side of the equation ( because `=` is to declare equations, it doesn't do the same as `=` in other languages, such as allocate the value in memory and give the memory pointer so you can change it or access to it) is bonded to the value in the left side. And values in Haskell are pure, `x` has the exact same value in all the execution of the program, will never change.

> Global variable accesses are external effects,

Yes, `x` is global, but that is a matter of scopes, I can do:

```
x = 5

f = \x -> 6 + x
```

and then

```
&> x
&> 5
&> y 4
$> 10
```

don't get confuse in that point